# ios crashing when I trigger actionsheet on load or on will appear

Tags: ios7

triggering an action sheet on view did load worked in ios 6 but it's crashing now on ios 7.  Moving it to viewWillAppear didn't help.  Triggering the action sheet from a button click after the view appears works fine.  Why won't it work in ios 7 now?

What's the recommended way to trigger the action sheet automatically when the view loads now?

```
 UIActionSheet *actionSheet;
    NSString* title  = @"update your public profile picture";

    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:title delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: @"Choose Existing Photo",  nil];     
    }
    else {
        actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:title delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Take Photo", @"Choose Existing Photo",  nil];   
    }

    [actionSheet showFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height) inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Comment: What's the error message when crash?

Comment: SIGABORT, when I look at crashalytics logs, I see Sheet can not be presented because the view is not in a window: